# Sum of ordinals must be equal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\Omega$ be a set of ordinals such that for all $\alpha \in \Omega: |\alpha| < \kappa$, for a fixed infinite cardinal $\kappa$. Let $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega$ and denote $\gamma=\text{inf}\lbrace \mu \in \Omega \mid \alpha + \mu \geq \beta \rbrace$ and $\delta=\text{inf}\lbrace \mu \in \Omega \mid \beta + \mu \geq \alpha \rbrace$. I'm trying to prove that $\alpha +\gamma=\beta + \delta$. By symmetry, it suffices to show that $\alpha + \gamma \leq \beta + \delta$. Suppose $\beta + \delta < \alpha + \gamma$, then $\alpha \leq \beta + \delta < \alpha + \gamma$. Intuitively, this must somehow imply there exists a $\theta \in \Omega$, with $\theta < \gamma$, such that $\beta + \delta=\alpha + \theta$. How does one find this $\theta$?

EDIT:

The answer goes as follows. Since the ordinals are totally ordered, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $\alpha \geq \beta$, i.e. $\gamma =0$. Therefore, it remains to show that $\alpha < \beta + \delta$ is impossible. So assume $\alpha < \beta + \delta$. If there exists an ordinal $\mu \in \Omega$ such that $\alpha \leq \beta + \mu$, then we obtain a contradiction with the minimality of $\delta$. Suppose for all $\mu < \delta: \beta + \mu < \alpha$. Then, $\beta + \delta \leq \beta + \text{sup}_{\mu < \delta}(\mu) \leq \alpha$, a contradiction.

Comment: So... $\Omega=\kappa$?

Comment: Also, why $\inf$ and not $\min$? Note that one of them has to be $0$, by the way.

Comment: It is just notation. Why do you mean by "one of them has to be 0" ?

Comment: Well, think about it.

Comment: Since the ordinals are totally ordered.

Comment: So assume w.l.o.g. that $\alpha \geq \beta$, i.e. $\gamma =0$. It then remains to show that $\alpha < \beta + \delta$ is impossible.

Comment: Well, you need to use the minimality of $\delta$ somehow, no?

Comment: If we can find an $\mu < \delta$ such that $\alpha \leq \beta + \mu$, then this contradicts the minimality of $\delta$. So suppose for all $\mu < \delta: \beta + \mu < \alpha$, then $\beta + \delta  \leq \beta + \text{sup}_{\mu < \delta}(\mu) \leq \alpha$ , a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: You should post your argument as an answer.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: I think it's better to post an answer, since it is an answer to your question.